# nohup: failed to run command `sh`: No such file or directory

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have the following pipeline script in Jenkins:

```
node {

  withMaven(globalMavenSettingsFilePath: '/my/path/apache-maven-3.2.2/conf/settings.xml', jdk: 'JDK 1.8.0u92', maven: 'apache-maven-3.2.2', mavenSettingsFilePath: '/my/path/apache-maven-3.2.2/conf/settings.xml') {

    sh '/my/path/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin/mvn clean install'
  }
}
```

For this, I am getting:

```
nohup: failed to run command `sh`: No such file or directory
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
```

Why is this?

I am sure that the path to my Maven installation is correct. When I run a job without the pipeline, Maven builds with no errors and I can see that it uses the same path.

Answer (score 7):

This might be the result of modifying `PATH`.

Check your script and Global Properties and remove modifications to `PATH`. It is now recommended to use `PATH+extra` instead. It would still be picked up, but without breaking actual `PATH`.

Related issue on Jenkins: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41339

Comment: Despite the low upvotes count, this was the solution for me!

Answer (score 3):

In the end, I used `shell` instead of `sh` and it worked. No idea why, they don't have a proper API.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use it like this:

```
  withMaven(
            maven: 'M3',
            mavenSettingsConfig: 'maven-settings-for-the-task',
            mavenLocalRepo: '.repository') {

        // Run the maven build
        sh "mvn clean install"
    }
```

Apart from that I would not use absolute paths to global settings.xml nor to user settings.xml. I would prefer using usage of "Config File Provider Plugin" which has the advantage to have the settings.xml on Master and available on all nodes.

See also the documentation: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin

Comment: One thing is that if I put `maven: 'M3'`, then it would say: `ERROR: Could not find 'M3' maven installation.`

Comment: You need to define Maven within the Jenkins Tools Configuration appropriate.

Comment: I already have set up Maven in `configureTools`. I selected `Install automatically` and `Version: 3.2.2`. Don't you think Jenkins should see this version of Maven?

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you are trying to run script copied from windows machine to unix machine.
YOU need to change the format to unix using :  **dos2unix <scriptname.sh>** and the run your script in unix **./<scriptname.sh>**